# Convert Data Type Ecommerce Variables in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

The Google documentation for e-commerce has data types https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en,

For example, **transactionTotal type = numeric**. If my developer passed it as a string, will the automatic data type conversion be applied to Google Analytics. In other words, does the service automatically convert types if they are set differently than in the documentation?

In https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/ Revenue (TransactionTotal) have type Currency... [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, the data is passed to the Google Server by requesting a transparent pixel from the Google Analytics server with the payload attached as query string.

"String" is a giveaway here, the query string would not preserve any data types.

Also, Javascript does not strongly enforce data types (and indeed does not have a currency type), and even if it did, the measurement protocol (on which current iterations of GA are built) is supposed to language agnostic and cannot make assumptions on what data types are supported by the client that makes the call.

So no matter from which perspective you look at it, what Google receives are strings. They need to be properly formed (e.g. numeric for metrics) and formatted strings, but they are strings nonetheless.

"Data type currency" might refer to the fact that GA is able to do currency conversions on this field (if the currency in your transaction and the currency set for the view are different), but from a code perspective this is just a float (or a numeric string with a point as decimal separator - in my experience passing floats and ints as quoted string will work, but might show up as wrong type in some debuggers). So this would refer to something internal to GA, not to your tracking code.

Comment: I understand correctly that since google analytics passes parameters through the example https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-77456218-1&cid=1410618336.1529141287&ec=email&ea=metka, all this data falls into analytics as a string. But ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/ shows examples of how metrics can be converted inside analytics, that is, they will work correctly, without any problems?

And if my developer formed an object with e-commerce data at a metric price products (type - string), will Google normally understand and pass the correct values?